# How do you put a carriage return into the field of an SQL statement using VB?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I want to insert a record using SQL and one of the fields needs to contain a carriage return, e.g.

Notes field:

```
Line 1 
Line 2 
End line
```

How would I code this SQL statement using VB

Comment: where are you getting your data from?

Comment: I'm inserting data into a proprietary accounting package called MYOB.  It uses a standard SQL insert statement, so I am building the insert statement.

Comment: Currently I have the usual "Insert into TableX (field1,field2) values ('field 1 value','field 2 value')"      but I want to put a few carriage returns into say field 2

Comment: But where are you putting those carriage returns? You need some kind of character or character sequence as a placeholder, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you build the insert statement, you store it in a string somewhere.  Add an escaped newline character into the string wherever you want the carrage returns to be.

A simple way to do that in VB would be:
`Sql = Sql & vbCrLf`

Comment: Thanks Jeff - I knew there had to be a simple way.

Answer (score 2):

Using SQL code:

```
UPDATE MyTable
   SET MyCol = MyCol + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10);
```